# Generic case for reacting to model value changes

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

I am writing a networked application. My model objects contain delegates that are called when a value changes. I have network objects that use the delegates to send the changed value over the network:

Model:

```
public class Person : AbstractModel
{
    public Action<string, ClientID> nameChangedDelegate;

    private string __name;

    public void setName(string name, ClientID id)
    {
        this.__name = name;
        this.nameChangedDelegate(name, id);
    }
}
```

Network:

```
public class PersonRelay : AbstractNetworkRelay<Person>
{
    public void connectDelegates()
    {
        this.modelObject.nameChangedDelegate += this.nameChanged;
    }

    public void nameChanged(string name, ClientID id)
    {
        this.sendStringOverNetwork(name, id, "setName");
    }

    public void setName(string name, ClientID id)
    {
        this.modelObject.setName(name, id);
    }
}
```

I have a lot of model objects in my application and most of them have a network relay. My current approach of connecting the delegate, sending the value over the network and receiving the value means there is a lot of repetative code written for every single property.

My question is: is there any way I can write a general case network object that:

- Detects when a value on the model has changed
- Sends the value over the network
- Receives the value
- Assigns the value to the correct parameter

Comment: This is besides the point... but you don't have to use this to access class members

Comment: Use should check for `nameChangedDelegate!=null` before invoking, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the Observer design pattern. If you use it you will have to register/unregister observer and the subject..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that using .Net reflection from a common base class.